# Resetting a variable to zero while in a loop

Tags: java

I have this code that allows me to take a string and replace all the vowels with an increasing number.

For example, "abababababababababababa" would give me "0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7b8b9b10b11". I am trying to keep it so that the number, once it goes past 9, resets to zero and starts counting back up again (so that "0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7b8b9b10b11" would instead read "0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7b8b9b0b1").

I can't figure out a way to do it within the loop that isn't fairly convoluted. If there is some way of achieving this that someone wouldn't mind divulging, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static String getNumberString( String s)
{
 String word = s;
 String word1 = word.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "@");
 int c = 0;

 String word2 =  word1;
 for( c = 0; c <= word.length(); c++)
 {
       word2 = word2.replaceFirst("@", Integer.toString(c));
 }

 return word2;
}
```

Comment: does it have to be increasing, or can it be random?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Modulus of 10 (% 10)`, this will wrap the count after the ninth digit to starting again.

```
public static String getNumberString(String s) {
        String word = s;
        String word1 = word.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "@");
        int c = 0;

        String word2 = word1;
        for (c = 0 ; c <= word.length() ; c++) {
            word2 = word2.replaceFirst("@", Integer.toString(c % 10));
        }

        return word2;
    }
```

**output**

```
0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7b8b9b0b1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel silly for not thinking of this. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Still have 41 seconds left :P

Answer (score 4):

How about using modulo?

```
word2 = word2.replaceFirst("@", Integer.toString(c % 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using modulus with ten.  It will cycle through because as it gets to a multiple of ten, the modulus will be 0 again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different variable other than `c` as the loop and by using and if condition you can check when `c` become `9` and reset it to `0`.

```
public static String getNumberString( String s)
{
 String word = s;
 String word1 = word.replaceAll("[AEIOUaeiou]", "@");
 int c = 0;

 String word2 =  word1;
 for(int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++)
 {
       word2 = word2.replaceFirst("@", Integer.toString(c));
       if(c == 9) {
           c = 0;
       } else {
           c++;
       }
 }

 return word2;
}
```

Comment: instead of c == 9, should be c > 9

Comment: @ankur-singhal what  is the problem with `c == 9`

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you can do

```
for (c = 0; c <= word.length(); c = (c + 1) % 10) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use c % 10 instead of c , like this code :

```
word2 = word2.replaceFirst("@", Integer.toString(c % 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of replacing with c you can use `c % 10`

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29). You can use `% 10` to ensure that the `count` wraps after the ninth digit. Also, I'd use a `StringBuilder`. Something like,

```
public static String getNumberString(String str) {
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (str != null) {
        for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
            switch (Character.toLowerCase(ch)) {
            case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
                sb.append(count);
                ++count;
                count %= 10;
                // or maybe, count = (count > 9) ? 0 : count;
                break;
            default:
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you can test it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String out = getNumberString("abababababababababababa");
    String expected = "0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7b8b9b0b1";
    System.out.println(out.equals(expected));
}
```

Output is

```
true
```